Difficulty using the ICU library convert UTF8 characters in C++
I am trying to use this code snippet from this Stack Overflow answer: A: How to convert an instance of std::string to lower case
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <unicode/locid.h>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    /*                          "Odysseus" */
    char const * someString = u8"ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ";
    icu::UnicodeString someUString( someString, "UTF-8" );
    // Setting the locale explicitly here for completeness.
    // Usually you would use the user-specified system locale,
    // which *does* make a difference (see ı vs. i above).
    std::cout << someUString.toLower( "el_GR" ) << "\n";
    std::cout << someUString.toUpper( "el_GR" ) << "\n";
    return 0;
}

This is not working for me. I am on a windows machine and I downloaded the windows 2019 ICU zip from this link: https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-72-1
and after downloading it, I linked it into my project. I made sure my system environment variables point to the bin64 folder of that library, and I linked the additional includes to the include folder, and I added the lib64 folder via my linker and I also went into linker -> input in the VS code settings and included 3 files there
icuuc.lib
icuin.lib
icuio.lib

The code is providing this output:
Original string: ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ
Lowercase:
Uppercase: ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ

when I do this
#include "io.h"
#include "windows.h"

void
io::testfn()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); //without this the letters are all "->->->..."
    /*                          "Odysseus" */
    char const* someString = u8"ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ";
    icu::UnicodeString someUString(someString, "UTF-8");
    std::cout << "Original string: " << someUString << std::endl;

    icu::UnicodeString lowerString = someUString.toLower("el_GR");
    icu::UnicodeString upperString = someUString.toUpper("el_GR");

    // Debugging: print the results
    std::cout << "Lowercase: " << lowerString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Uppercase: " << upperString << std::endl;
}

I have tried saving the file using save as -> 'save with encoding' and UTF8 without signature is providing the above output and anything else I try is worse. Why can't I do this? Also is there no easier way to make a string "tolower" in c++? I was making my own tolower function but my bf who is a c++ dev told me I should use the boost library but then on the linked stackoverflow it says not to use boost because it will cause unseen errors.
I have tried reading about this and using ai and asking other programmers I know.
Also if I do this:
    icu::UnicodeString englishString = someUString.toUpper("en_US");
    std::cout << "English: " << englishString << std::endl;

then I get this output
Original string: ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ
Lowercase:
Uppercase: ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ
English: ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ


Are you compiling with CL.EXE /utf-8 flag?

I think this line char const * someString = u8"ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ" is invalid in C++20 because u8 literals have the type of char8_t not char. Your code works for me on Linux. If all else fails, wide strings work on Windows so you may want to try those (no need of libicu or boost).

Honestly I don't know how to know what flags I am compiling with because I haven't used make with c++ myself, I just hit run in VS so idk what flags are being used or how to know. I also don't know how to use wide strings but I will look into that.

VS lets you set additional compiler flags at the same place it lets you set additional libraries and include directories.

I set the flag and also tried using wstrings and neither worked for me yet. I am getting the same output of a blank string and it says 16 after.

Have you tried using std::wcout instead of std::cout?

I tried using wcout and it was not working. idk if it was because it couldn't convert from u8 to wstring or what really. I couldn't get it to run at all with wcout.
char8_t const* someString = u8"ΟΔΥΣΣΕΥΣ";

std::wstring(someString);
std::wcout << someUString;

It was also previously working with the const char* u8"..." but now it is telling me that u8 cannot be const char* and it needs to be char8_t now but then that doesn't convert or something.
